# Django: how to get Userprofile instances in template, having OneToOne relationship with auth.User model?

Tags: python, django, django-users

I have a UserProfile in my models, with OneToOne relationship with User model.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=False)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True, null=True)
```

In my template, I need to get data of a user, but not only username, email and name, which are fields of User, but birthday and image also. As I saw in my database, user data and userprofile data are two different tables.

But, I can't get instances of Userprofile class. `Hello, {{ user.first_name }}!` works. I'm afraid, I don't understand some concepts of using current instance in the template. Can you explain me that?

So, I tried this:

EDIT:

```
This is a user birthday: {{ user.birthday }} #doesn't work
This is a user birthday: {{ user.profile.birthday }} #WORKS!
This is a user birthday: {{ userprofile.birthday }} #doesn't work
```

Please, help me. I've spend too much time to understand that, unsuccessfully.

Comment: The second one is correct and should work.

Comment: @DanielRoseman oh God, you're right. Probably, I had a mistake somewhere. Thanks.